# Erro No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

Para ajudar quem esta passando pelo mesmo problema (**RESPOSTA ABAIXO**).

Cenário: Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ASP.NET CORE MVC onde estou trabalhando com HttpContextAccessor e ocorre o erro abaixo.

Erro:

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' has been registered.
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema ocorre porque por padrão o `IHttpContextAccessor`  não vem mais conectado.

Para solucionar esse problema devemos conectar/registrar manualmente o serviço dentro da classe `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); // Adicione eessa linha para que seu projeto volte a funcionar normalmente.
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]